# setw() not working properly on my code

Tags: c++

I'm having problem with my code not sure if it's a bug or there is something wrong with my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << setfill('*') << setw(80) << "*";
cout << setw(21) <<  "Mt.Pleasant Official Billing Statement" << endl;
cout << setfill('*') << setw(80) << "*" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Adding manual spaces works but I want to add spaces programmatically but when I tested the application this what it looks like :

[image]

Comment: It's working exactly how it's supposed to. If you specifically want 21 extra spaces or something, put them in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[setw](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/) **does not** move the text but sets the minimum width it should take

To achieve what you have in mind you should experiment with a bigger value since your string is longer than 21 characters, e.g.

```
cout << setfill('*') << setw(80) << "*" << endl;
cout  << setfill(' ') << setw(56) <<  "Mt.Pleasant Official Billing Statement" << endl;
cout << setfill('*') << setw(80) << "*" << endl;
```

Output:

```
********************************************************************************
                  Mt.Pleasant Official Billing Statement
********************************************************************************
```